# ACodec configureCodec returning error -38

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am trying to configure a video encoder using `MediaCodec` for mime=video/avc, width=1920, height=1080.
Unfortunately the device complains with the following log:

```
12-20 13:11:49.410 5781-5817/ I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
12-20 13:11:49.423 5781-5817/ E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.encoder] configureCodec returning error -38
12-20 13:11:49.424 5781-5817/ E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
12-20 13:11:49.424 5781-5816/ E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 3
12-20 13:11:49.425 5781-5801/ E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0x80001001, resetting...
12-20 13:11:49.433 5781-5817/com.humaneyes.filesave I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
```

Answer (score 1):

Some codecs are finicky and require special properties.

> Failing to specify some of these can cause the MediaCodec configure()
>   call to throw an unhelpful exception.

Must define the following integer properties in the `MediaFormat` at a minimum:

- MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE
- MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE
- MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL
- MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT

For example:

```
MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1920, 1080);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 2000000);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);
```